# Proving something is true in Boolean Algebra given two equations and two variables without using a Truth Table

Tags: boolean-algebra

Problem:

Given that $$ AB = 0$$ and $$A + B = 1$$ and using only algebraic manipulation is it possible to prove that: $$ \overline A = B$$

Answer:

I believe it is, but I have failed in my attempt to do so. I can verify it using a truth table. Here is my attempt.

\begin{align*}\
AB &= \overline { A + B } \\
AB &= \overline A \, \overline B \\
AAB &= A \overline A \, \overline B \\
AB &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: FWIW, the first line of your attempt is incorrect, \$AB = !(!{A}+!{B})\$, not what you wrote. What you wrote implies that AND and NOR are equivalent operators.

Comment: @ThePhoton Did you miss the fact that we were given AB = 0 and A + B = 1?

Comment: Sorry, thought you were writing an identity, not an inference from the givens. In that case, consider combining the identity (my version) with the inference (your version).

Comment: Haven't taken this course, but can you use the identity law to substitute B and then find A from the other identity law?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try proof by contradiction.

Assume: $$A = B$$ and show that leads to a contradiction. Your first statement says

$$AB = 0$$ so if $$A = B$$ then $$AA = 0$$ and thus $$A = 0$$

.. and you can take it from there.

Comment: I can take it from here. However, based upon the question in the book, I do not think the author of the book would consider an indirect proof as correct. Can you do it using a direct proof? Thanks Bob.